# ADB devices list empty with wireless debugging

Tags: android, adb, android-wireless

I have Android 11 on my phone, I have setup **Wireless Debugging**, and in the list of Paired Devices my computer shows up. However, when I run `adb devices -l` on my computer, the list of devices is empty.

Why am I seeing an empty list. Is there something extra that I need to do?

Here is the device:

[image: Device]

Here is the terminal:

[image: Terminal]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You will need to connect to the device before it becomes visible in `adb devices -l`. You must run `adb connect ipaddress:port`, in your case `adb connect 192.168.1.123:37457`. [Docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+:%7E:text=(For%20Linux%20or%20Microsoft%20Windows%20only),address%20and%20port%20under%20Wireless%20debugging.)

Comment: No it is a different command, the one responsible for pairing is `adb pair ipaddr:port` but `adb connect ipaddr:port` is used to connect to the device after being paired.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. Thanks for the help. The doc I was using didn't say you needed to run the `connect` command.

Comment: Sure most welcome, please mark the answer as accepted in order to help the others who might stumble upon this in the future.

Comment: Not working for me. Failed to connect to 'ip:port': Connection refused.

Comment: That's right, you must use the `connect` after the `pair`, but be careful and specify the `ip:port` from the main wifi debugging settings page and not the ones used in the `pair` command.

Comment: @maXp I think your comment should be part of the answer.

Comment: I was having connectivity issues in UI, so checked commandline . After that even with pair its not working.. connect saved me . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Step 01: turn on wireless debugging

Step 02: click on "Pair device with pairing code"
[Step 02 outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drPCm.png)

Step 03: in cmd enter "`adb pair ipaddress:hostname`" (the ip address will be
displayed on the screen after opening window in the previous step)

Step 04: enter the pairing code displayed on the android screen to the cmd

Step 05: in cmd enter "`adb connect ipaddress:hostname`"

```
(this ip address is diffrent from the previous one 
{displayed on wireless debugging window, not in the popup window})
```

[wireless debugging window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqRUs.png)

Step 06: now `adb devices` should show your device

Happy Hacking

Answer (score -1):

It says unknown command adb pair
Saw the help there is no pair command listed in the menu

Instead go to platform-tools folder in my case `~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools` from here you can execute `./adb` and then in the help you can see there the pair option
`./adb pair <ipaddress>:<port>` will prompt for pairing code

Then you are sucessfully connected

[image]